# How to change max_length of Django's username field

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm using the default Django User backend. I just want to make one small change: reduce the `max_length` of `username` to 30 (I believe the default is 150). How would I achieve this?

I'm using [django-allauth](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html) as my user account framework and here is my current custom allauth signup form:

**draft1/forms**

```
class AllauthSignupForm(forms.Form):

    captcha = ReCaptchaField(
        public_key=config("RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY"),
        private_key=config("RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY"),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User 

    def signup(self, request, user):
        """ Required, or else it throws deprecation warnings """
        pass
```

**draft1/settings.py**

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'draft1.forms.AllauthSignupForm'
```

Any idea how I can change the `username` max_length to 30?

Comment: You want to set max lenght after you set in forms.py ??

Comment: Before or after, whatever works

Comment: Why would you create duplicate of your own question?